# DB Schema for an application

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, database-schema

I've an application, where I need to post comments on blog paragraphs, not comment on blogs. The paragraphs are separated by two new-line characters.

I'll splitting the post received using `post.split('\n\n')`, saving the post and paragraphs in separate tables (`Blog` and `Paragraphs`). Now whenever a new comment is received, I'll be saving it in the `Comments` table with the para_id received.

Following is the DB schema that I'm planning to build.

Table **Blog**

```
-id
-title
-date
```

Table **Paragraphs**

```
-id
-para
-sequence_no
-blog_id(FK)
```

Table **Comments**

```
-id
-comment
-para_id(FK)
-date
```

The above design has some flaw. Consider an example when a post is updated, ie, either a new paragraph is inserted between two paragraphs, or a paragraph is completely removed. This would result in distortion of the sequence(ordinal number). How would I handle such a use-case?

Comment: You would update the sequence id accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Calculate an unique hash value for each paragraph and use combination of PostID+ParagraphHash as primary key.

Store timestamp along with each paragraph. Every time user edits the post, update timestamp for existing paragraphs. It will be easy to spot deleted paragraphs.

Comment: Additionally, you could logically delete instead of physically delete the paragraph.  Sequencing of paragraphs is going to be more of an issue in the case of reordering or deletion/insertion.  In those cases, I would recommend the creation of a meta document construct that maintains the sequencing external from the paragraph entities themselves. In other words, move the sequencing out of the paragraph.